# Python Win32 Outlook.Application failure

Tags: python, outlook

I am using win32com.client to manipulate emails and attachments. My jobs run just fine when I am running them interactively. However when I schedule the jobs in Windows Task Scheduler and try to run under the option 'Run whether the user is logged on not', because this is supposed to run without any intervention, it does not work but times out waiting to open a session in outlook.  If I select the option 'Run only when the user is logged on' and run the job it runs without a flaw. How do I get around this issue?

Thanks
VR

Answer (score 0):

Outlook (and other Office applications) are not designed to run in the context of a scheduled task or Windows service: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/257757/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office